# Failing to run Java with the error "/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory"

Tags: java, jdk

I just installed JDK in Ubuntu. When I want to use the `java` command, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

but I declare the java home using `update-alternatives`:

```
update-alternatives --config java
There is 1 choice for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                   Priority   Status    
------------------------------------------------------------     
   0            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   1         auto mode    
 * 1            /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java   1         manual mode    

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

Even when I run java in */usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/* directory, it doesn't recognize it.
Thanks for any help.

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/55960/654950) answer, but it didn't help me and I still have the same error.

Comment: Which `JAVA_HOME` did you declare?

Comment: Run that command like this `/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -version` and place that path in your `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file

Comment: @George Udosen steel same error   /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java -version
bash: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_111/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: How did you install Java?